# Solving an exercise about admissible coefficient values for a MA(1) process

Tags: time-series, correlation, autocorrelation, eigenvalues, moving-average

I'm studying "Principles of system identification : Theory and Pratice" by Arun K. Tangirala and well... I've just entered the part about moving averages and I'm confused. I don't understand some assumptions around white noise, stationary processes and autoregressive models. I'll illustrate my problems on the following exercise:

The problem is exercise E8.3 p 203 and it states :

"Show that for a MA(1) process $v[k]=e[k]+c_1 e[k-1]$, the ACVF sequence $\sigma_{vv}(l)$ is non negative definite whenever $\vert c_1\vert \geq \frac{1}{2}$"

Here is what I did so far :

from a computation made somewhere else in the book around the same problem, which seems to work if you assume $\mu_v=0$ (more on that later) we have, $e$ being a white noise process :
$$
\begin{align}
\sigma_{vv}(l) &= E[(v[k]-\mu_v)(v[k-l]-\mu_v)]\\
&=E[(e[k]+c_1e[k-1])(e[k-l]+c_1e[k-l-1])]\\
&= E[e[k]e[k-l]] + c_1E[e[k]e[k-l-1]]\\
&+c_1E[e[k-1]e[k-l]] + c_1^{2}E[e[k-1]e[k-l-1]]\\
&=\sigma_{ee}[l] + c_1\sigma_{ee}[l+1] + c_1\sigma_{ee}[l-1]+c_1^{2}\sigma_{ee}[l]
\end{align}
\label{eq1}\tag{1}$$

Now if we agree with this we might proceed and (try to?) solve the exercise. According to the result of \ref{eq1} the variance-autocovariance matrix is then :
$$\sigma_{e}^{2}\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}1+c_1^{2} & c_1\\c_1&1+c_1^{2}\end{bmatrix}}_{A}\label{eq2}\tag{2}$$

A quick examination of $A$ can show that $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ are eigenvectors of $A$ for the respective eigenvalues $\lambda_1(c_1) = c_1^{2} + c_1 + 1$ and $\lambda_2(c_1) = c_1^{2} - c_1 + 1$

$\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ reach their minimum respectively for $c_1 = -\frac{1}{2}$ and $c_1 = \frac{1}{2}$. Once plugged-in they both give $\lambda_{1_{min}} = \frac{3}{4}$ and $\lambda_{2_{min}} = \frac{3}{4}$.

This means that $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ only have complex roots and will remain strictly positive for any $c_1$. To my knowledge this means that A will be definite positive no matter the (real) value of $c_1$. So either my reasoning or the exercise is broken.

Here are my questions :

1. Is my calculation right? How am I supposed to find a condition on $c_1$? In general is that a thing to show that AR coefficients have to compel to the positivity of the variance-autocovariance matrix?
2. Between the first and second line of \ref{eq1} it is assumed that $\mu_v=0$ which happens if $\mu_e=0$. The author seems to do that a lot in he book without explanation. In this book white noise is *only* defined as a stationary process $e$ verifying $$\sigma_{e}^{2}[l] = \delta_{l0}$$ so there is no mention of zero mean. Is it a forgotten assumption? Does the stationarity of $v$ imply the zero mean of $e$ (if so, how?)? Do white noises always have zero mean? In essence why exactly do we have $E[v[k]]=0$ in general?

Comment: I think you have to consider the covariance matrix of a larger number of observations, say that of $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$.  These observations have a tridiagonal covariance matrix with smallest eigenvalue given by https://math.stackexchange.com/a/179900/348271.  For $c_1=\pm 1$, the smallest eigenvalue tends zero as $n\rightarrow\infty$.  Hence the autocovariance function is only positive _semi_-definite.

Comment: @JarleTufto Thank you for your comment! I looked at the original document and it's pretty hairy. I imagine you were referring to the formula $\lambda_k = 1+c_1^{2}+2|c_1|cos(\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2n})$. The problem arrives just after introducing MA processes in the book so I imagine there is something simpler. Plus it doesn't disqualify $|c_1|<\frac{1}{2}$. But the tridiagonal matrix eigenvalues formula is cool!

Comment: If you consider the infinite covariance matrix $\boldsymbol\Sigma$ of $(\dots,v_{-1},v_0,v_1,\dots)$ it is clear, in the case of $c_1=1$, that $\mathbf{x}=(\dots,-1,+1,-1,+1,\dots)$ is an eigenvector of $\boldsymbol\Sigma$ with $\lambda=0$ as the associated eigenvalue.  So in this sense, the autocovariance function is only semi positive-definite.